# Need help in JavaScript working with arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am sort of new to JavaScript (Just started using it in school) and I have been looking around to get this program done for class. For some reason I just cant get it to work properly (with whatever I currently am working on) I am trying to fill up an Player Object with an array of Missle Objects... Before switching my code to this use of objects, I was able to display the "missles" but now I'm stuck.

I am only placing my necessary code:

```
function Player(){
    this.x = c.width/2;
    this.y = c.height-20;
    this.w = 50;
    this.h = 10;
    this.dx = 30;
    this.score = 0;
    this.missles = new Array();}

function Missle(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dy = 10;
    this.w = 8;
    this.h = 8;
    this.visible = "false";}


function init1P(){
if (playing == "true"){
    player = new Player();
    animate1P();
}}

function animate1P(){
cntxt.clearRect( 0, 0, c.width, c.height );

cntxt.fillStyle="#000000";
cntxt.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

cntxt.fillStyle="#ffffff";
cntxt.font="34px Verdana";
cntxt.fillText(player.score, 10, c.height-10);  

cntxt.fillStyle="#ffffff";

cntxt.fillRect(player.x,player.y,player.w,player.h);

//cntxt.fillRect(comp.x,comp.y,comp.w,comp.h);

if ( player.missles.visible == "true" ) {
    cntxt.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    cntxt.fillRect( player.missles.x, player.missles.y, player.missles.w, player.missles.h );
    //isHit();
    if ( hit == "false" ) {
        player.missles.y -= player.missles.dy;
        if ( player.missles.y <= 0 ) {
            player.missles.visible = "false";
        }
    }
}

// request new frame
if ( playing == "true" ) {
    requestFrame( function() { animate1P(); } );
}

//moveComp();
checkBoundaries(player);
//checkBoundaries(comp);
//isHit(player);
//isHit(comp);  }

function shoot() {
player.missles.push(new Missle(player.x + player.w/2, player.y + 10));
player.missles.visible = "true";
hit = "false";}
```

Comment: Do you expect each player to have multiple missles? Currently, you have an array and `push` missles to it, but at the same time you act as if there is only one missle by doing e.g. `missles.visible`.

Comment: Well, there is only going to be one player... I'm trying to create a Space Invaders game for class... So the one player is supposed to have missles and i would like more than 1 missle to appear on the screen at a time... Thank you for the fast response!

Comment: @steveax Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag). D34thSt4lker: if you have a new question, ask it separately.

Comment: @Gilles noted. I'll help with the cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your player is supposed to have several missles, which you denoted by using an array:

```
this.missles = new Array();
```

When using an array, you have to loop (using e.g. `for`) to apply something to each element. So, doing `player.missles.visible = "false"` really just sets a property on the array itself, and not on each element. You'd have to do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < player.missles.length; i++) {
  player.missles[i].visible = "false";  // player.missles[i] is one item on each iteration
}
```

The same goes for the drawing: fetch and update data of each missle in a loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < player.missles.length; i++) {
  if ( player.missles[i].visible == "true" ) {
    // ...
}
```

Also, note that there are booleans in JavaScript. You can use just `true`/`false`, and you can then directly use an `if` like this:

```
if(player.missles[i].visible) {
  // ...
```

Comment: Hey @pimvdb not sure yet how this forum works but i edited my initial question (1 more question) and thought maybe you can help me out again... Thanks!! Much appreciated

Comment: Nevermind... I realized that I had my array named "points" and was using "pos" to fill it up... Thank you anyways!!